# vector that stores reversed data

Tags: c++, vector, containers

I work with a protocol that refers to things in a list by index. The natural way to store those things is in a vector, so I can random-access in constant time. But by nature there is a lot of fiddling at the beginning of the vector, including inserts and deletes. The lower the index, the more fiddling.
The result is a lot of copying the rest of the vector.

I'd like to store things the opposite way, lower protocol-indices at higher vector-indices (i.e. higher address), to minimize the contents shifting, but still be able to random-access elements transparently by-protocol-indices. The ideal container would be a drop-in replacement of std::vector, except for pointer arithmetics and alikes. I still want pointer arithmetics, but can handle reverse order myself.

Is there any such class around ?

Maybe some boost container I couldn't find or some obscure policy ?

**EDIT:** Actually, it stroke me that I could use a kind of vector that reserves space *before* index `0` as well as after index `length-1`. Deque is not built like that as i thought, it uses chunks of memory instead, preventing pointer arithmetics.

Comment: You could use something like a `deque`.

Comment: `deque` offers optimized inserts at the start of the container if that is the only kind you need

Comment: Is there a reason why a `map` wouldn't work?  It's constant time, though slower than a vector, if you use it "array-like" for the key, and you solve the allocation problem.

Comment: @Gabriel have you timed it? is it a problem? vector is one of the fastest containers there is even with shifting.

Comment: this question is under-specified

Answer (score 1):

From your description it sounds as if items are inserted and deleted at the front of a vector, causing the rest of the vector to be shifted. Which if so means that you're not depending on items staying at specific indices. Which raises the question of why the inserts and deletes are at the front of the vector -- to maintain a sort order?

There are many containers in the C++ standard library that maintains a sort order with logarithmic time inserts and deletes, e.g. `std::multi_set`.

When the inserts and deletes are very localized, as it sounds like (but your're not really clear), you can probably use a **cursor gap** structure, also known as a **[gap buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gap_buffer)**, to reduce inserts and deletes to constant time, keeping constant time indexing. One cost is that indexing involves an additional indirection. But this may be premature optimization, so **MEASURE** if the perfromance is important.

Comment: I passively receive data. The sender maintains such a vector, too, and it takes inserts and deletes into account when providing indices.

Comment: @Gabriel: well with the sender maintaining a dynamic index association, standard library containers do not help you, but a cursor gap structure might. still if the vector is short then introducing that structure may not necessarily improve performance. the direct approach might then possibly be best, in the same way that an O(n^2) algorithm can outperform an O(n) algorithm for a sufficiently small data set.